# Does Adblock plugins block image pop-ups

Tags: javascript, jquery, adblock

I was wondering if Adblock plugins block pop-ups from plugins like Fancybox and other image galleries, when it uses Javascript/jQuery?

I couldn't seem to find anything on Google.

Comment: This doesn't seem to look like a programming question. If it is, could you please add more details to the question so that this is clear? This site is specifically for programming questions.

Comment: As far as I know, AdBlock doesn't do anything about popups. It works within the page to hide ads it knows about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From AdBlock Plus website

> **How does Adblock Plus work?**
>
> Adblock Plus itself has no functionality; it doesn't block anything
> until you "tell" it what to block by adding external filter lists.
> Filter lists are essentially an extensive set of rules that tell
> Adblock Plus which elements of a website to block. You can add any
> filter list you want. For example, block tracking or malware. You can
> also create your own filter lists. Almost all filters are open source,
> therefore many filter lists have been created by Internet users.
>
> Filter lists enabled by default include:
>
> An ad-blocking list selected based on your language (EasyList) The
> Acceptable Ads list These are enabled to get you started. You can
> remove them or add others - it's up to you.
>
> EasyList corresponds to your browser language and is aimed at
> disabling ads that are considered to be intrusive by our community of
> users. Eyeo GmbH did not draft EasyList and therefore has no right to,
> or control over, its content. Visit the EasyList Community for more
> information.
>
> The Acceptable Ads list displays ads that comply with the acceptable
> ads criteria agreed upon by our community of users. The list is
> maintained by Eyeo GmbH.

Example of filter list: https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt

If you don't want to your gallery or whatever to be blocked just don't include `ad` in it. AdBlocks are not so smart, therefore they are not intrusive.